# JavaScript: very poor performance when using await in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've been fighting with the very poor performance of one of my lib that makes extensive use of async/await to deal with mixed types of functions and I can't find an explanation. I was able to reduce my code to a very simple test case:

```
function a() {
    return 'a';
}

async function start() {
    await a();
}

start();
```

In a real case scenario, my lib doesn't know if `a` is a sync or async function so it uses await to support both cases. But it makes the performance extremely slowy compared to this:

```
function a() {
    return 'a';
}

function start() {
    a();
}

start();
```

I created a jsperf that seems to confirm my impressions:

https://jsperf.com/classic-function-call-vs-await/1

Is this a known issue? Am I using async/await incorrectly?

Comment: you are using await inside async start function which will wait till the promise gets resolved

Comment: add alert below , await a(), you will see that start() gets paused untill a() gets resolved due to await then it throw alert message

Comment: @NagaSaiA, yes, of course it is paused. But it is also paused when not using async/await. My point is that it is paused way longer.

Comment: Just try to use a promise. You get even worse results. Async functions are expensive. Thats probably why web workers are here.

Comment: @bigless No. Web workers have nothing to do with async/await or promises.

Comment: Well in the jsperf the functions are not doing any actual work, so the overhead of the promise creation will be very pronounced. Please post your actual code that is slow, not a toy example.

Comment: @Bergi, the overhead is exactly the problem. My code execute hundred of thousands calls to some functions, some async, some sync, and even an overhead of 0.1ms leads to tens of seconds of difference in the final performance.

Comment: @EricMORAND Well I could comfort you saying that engines will eventually optimise the overhead away, but for now you will need to live with it. If you want help with how to improve your code, or advice on using async/await "correctly", you will need to post your actual code.